# Help with function advice: Unknown add-function location ‘asm-calculate-indentation’

Tags: hooks, advice

I'm trying to modify how `asm-mode` does its automatic indentation.
I thought I would use the following:

```el
(defun yasm-calculate-indentation (oldfun)
  "Add the formatting for a few other keywords I like."
  (cond
   ((looking-at-p "section") 0)         ; section
   ((looking-at-p "global") 0)          ; global
   ((looking-at-p "extern") 0)          ; extern
   (:default (oldfun))))

(add-hook 'asm-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (advice-add :around #'asm-calculate-indentation
                        #'yasm-calculate-indentation)))
```

However I'm getting the error: `Unknown add-function location ‘asm-calculate-indentation’`

Leaving me rather confused.

Am I adding the hook in the wrong location to be able to access that name?

I tried adding the advice from the minibuffer when editing an assembly file but it gave me the same error.

This is my first time trying to use advice so maybe that's where I'm going wrong...
How can I get this to work?

Comment: Drew's answer correctly identifies the source of the error message, but there are some additional problems with this code. (a) `oldfun` is not the name of a function, but rather a local variable whose value is a function, so it must be called as `(funcall oldfun)`. (b) There is no need to call `advice-add` from a hook function. You can advise symbols before they are defined as functions; this is called forward advice. Furthermore, the hook will run every time `asm-mode` is enabled, whereas the advice needs only be registered once.

Comment: @basil: Please consider putting such info in an answer. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: @Drew Done, please review.

Comment: @Basil: Looks good to me. Thx.

Comment: thanks to you both for the help! works great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drew's [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/57578/15748) correctly identifies the source of the error message, but there are some additional problems with the code.

```el
(defun yasm-calculate-indentation (oldfun)
  "Add the formatting for a few other keywords I like."
  (cond
   ((looking-at-p "section") 0)         ; section
   ((looking-at-p "global") 0)          ; global
   ((looking-at-p "extern") 0)          ; extern
   (:default (oldfun))))
```

First, `oldfun` is not the name of a function, but rather a local variable whose value is a function, so it must be called as `(funcall oldfun)` instead of `(oldfun)`.

```el
(add-hook 'asm-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (advice-add :around #'asm-calculate-indentation
                        #'yasm-calculate-indentation)))
```

Second, there is no need to call `advice-add` from a hook function. You can advise symbols before they are defined as functions; this is called forward advice.

Furthermore, `asm-mode-hook` will run every time `asm-mode` is enabled, whereas the advice needs only be registered once.

Putting all of this together:

```el
(define-advice asm-calculate-indentation (:before-until () my-keywords)
  "Determine indentation for a few other keywords I like.
If this advice returns non-nil, that value is used and
`asm-calculate-indentation' is not called; otherwise the value
returned by `asm-calculate-indentation' is used."
  (and (looking-at-p (rx (or "section" "global" "extern")))
       0))
```

The convenience macro `define-advice` was added in Emacs 25; in Emacs 24 you can emulate it as follows:

```el
(defun yasm-calculate-indentation ()
  "Determine indentation for a few other keywords I like.
Intended as :before-until advice for `asm-calculate-indentation'."
  (and (looking-at-p (rx (or "section" "global" "extern")))
       0))

(advice-add 'asm-calculate-indentation :before-until
            #'yasm-calculate-indentation)
```

Answer (score 2):

```el
(advice-add :around #'asm-calculate-indentation #'yasm-calculate-indentation)
```

should be

```el
(advice-add #'asm-calculate-indentation :around #'yasm-calculate-indentation)
```

`C-h f advice-add` says:

```
advice-add is a compiled Lisp function in `nadvice.el'.

(advice-add SYMBOL WHERE FUNCTION &optional PROPS)

Like `add-function' but for the function named SYMBOL.
...
```

`C-h f add-function` says:

```
add-function is a Lisp macro in `nadvice.el'.

(add-function WHERE PLACE FUNCTION &optional PROPS)

...
```

The error message tells you that `asm-calculate-indentation` is not a known `add-function` location:

```
error: Unknown add-function location ‘asm-calculate-indentation’
```

The known locations are listed in `C-h f add-function`: `:around` etc.

Comment: wow that is  a frustrating change in argument order... thanks!